# Can I apply exception handling to an enpoint like @GetMapping("organizations/{id}/applications")?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I was able to introduce exception handling but I could only really manage to apply it to endpoints that retrieved a specific id

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {


    @Query("FROM Organization WHERE name =?1")
    Organization findByOrganizationNameLike(@Param("name") String name);

}

// service class method
public Organization getOrganizationById(final Long id){
        return organizationRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow((ResourceNotFoundException::new));
    }

//related controller method
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Organization> getOrganizationByID(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(organizationService.getOrganizationById(id));
    }
```

I am not sure if it can be applied to an endpoint such as `@GetMapping("/{id}/applications")` which returns a list of applications associated with a particular organization's id. However, I think it should because if I enter an invalid id into the above endpoint I get a 500 error that isn't handled nicely.

I want to be able to handle the fact that if I pass an invalid organization id into an endpoint like `organizations/{id}/applications` the exception will be handled gracefully.

The issue as I see it seems to me that I can’t call the `orElseThrow` method from a custom repository method such as `findById(id)`.

```
// can invoke exception handling
public Organization getOrganizationById(final Long id){
        return organizationRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow((ResourceNotFoundException::new));
    }

// can't invoke exception handling
public List<Application> getAllApplicationsWithOrganizationId(final Long id){
        return organizationRepository.findById(id).get().getApplications();
    }
```

Am I correct in my assumption?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The method `orElseThrow` is from Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class. If you instead call the `get()` method, you will no longer have an Optional, but whatever it contains.

What you could do, is use the `map()` method. This takes the value in the `Optional` and applies a method to it, or gives an empty `Optional` if there was no value. After `map`, you can again use `orElseThrow`. Like so:

```java
organizationRepository.findById(id)
    .map(Organization::getApplications)
    .orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
```

Comment: Perfect Rick, I did just that and it solved my problem. 
I was aware of the optional issue but thought there was no getting around it as I thought I needed to call `get()` to access `getApplications()` method.

And yes I was extending a jpaRepository. 

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Also consider updating your question with some additional details, like the code for the organizationRepository. It will help future readers who are struggeling with the same problem.

Comment: I tried to accept the answer, but I don't have enough Stack overflow credits to do so. Perhaps you could help me out. 

I'll update the question with additional information to help future users.

Comment: I've upvoted your edited question, maybe that will be enough. If not, then don't worry about it :)

Comment: Done, see in kind. :)